# Python - list elements multiplication without loops

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a numpy array which elements contains products of some increasing number of elements of some other numpy array in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
def foo(n):
    return(365-n)/365
#lim is some integer greater than 0 and less than 365
lim = 50
x = np.arange(0, lim, 1)
#foo(n) is some function
y = foo(x)
z = np.zeros(np.shape(x))
#z is the variable I'm trying to create
for i in x:
    z[i] = 1 - np.prod(y[0:i+1])
```

Does anyone know how to write it without using a loop? I was advised by pretty much everyone to avoid using loops in python, because it's inefficient and as you can probably see I'm not a very skilled programmer.

Comment: You may avoid for-loop when this is another option, by you're gonna use hundred of times because there is no other, do no thing of throw forloop away each time

Comment: What is `lim`? What is `foo`? You're correct that loops should be avoided if possible, but you need a [mcve] so we can actually work on it on our end

Comment: @azro I can't follow what you're saying there at all btw, sorry

Comment: `I was advised to avoid using loops in python` : when you can. But hundred of times you **will use** loop because that how to solve the problem

Comment: There will be a `for` loop somewhere, but what they are probably referring to is an explicit _python_ loop. If it can be pushed into numpy as a vectorized operation, then that's preferable

Comment: I made an edit so it's kina more clear.

Comment: `z = 1-np.cumprod(y)`, without the `for` loop? It's out by 1 index from your current approach since you have two `0` values at the start. Is that intentional?

Comment: @roganjosh not really intentional. I'll try to make it right.

Comment: In that case, even better, cos I've just given you an answer that doesn't do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that Python loops should be avoided if you can vectorize the computation. There is no reason to initialise `z` with zeros. Your current output for `z` is:

```
array([0.        , 0.        , 0.00273973, 0.00820417, 0.01635591,
       0.02713557, 0.04046248, 0.0562357 , 0.07433529, 0.09462383,...]
```

I'm not sure whether the double `0` values are actually desirable (I'll update if so). The simplest drop-in replacement for the current approach is just using [`numpy.cumprod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html?highlight=cumprod#numpy.cumprod):

```
import numpy as np

def foo(n):
    return(365-n)/365

lim = 50
x = np.arange(0, lim, 1)

y = foo(x)
z = 1 - np.cumprod(y)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for. You're also correct that `z[1]` shouldn't be `0`, but I made an edit, which yields correct sequence.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a for in one line

```py
z = [(1 - np.prod(y[0:i])for i in x)]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your response, but I'm not trying to write a shorter code. I'm asking if there's some obvious way to avoid a for loop here.